# "that name is not available" for all gcs buckets

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Really struggling to deploy my application with Terraform on gcp. The issue I am running to is I constantly am getting an error:

googleapi: Error 409: Sorry, that name is not available. Please try a different one., conflict

my_test_upload_bucket_udybmn_anitoy

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "test_upload_bucket" {
  name     = var.upload_bucket
  location = "northamerica-northeast1"
  lifecycle_rule {
  action {
    type = "SetStorageClass"
     storage_class = "COLDLINE"
  }
  condition {
    age = 14
  }
}
}
```

Would really appreciate help here as this is driving me nuts

wondering can someone point me in a direction as I have also tried adding random strings to the end to no avail

I am expecting to create buckets as name is unique but to no avail

Comment: Familiar with GCP but not as familiar with the Terraform provider. IIUC you need to set `name` to be the bucket's name. You have `"var.upload_bucket"`. The period (`.`) will require verification but it is also invalid (needs to be DNS). I think where you have `"test_upload_bucket"` may correspond to the GCP project name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCS bucket names are globally unique, meaning that no two buckets may hold the same name. Try prefixing the name with a GUID or some other random string (see docs on bucket naming practices [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#naming)).

Also note that if you previously created and deleted a bucket with the same name, you might have to wait a while before the name is released for usage again.

Comment: There's something very wrong with the way GCP does bucket names. I just generated a largely arbitrary 51 character name with a bunch of random letters and numbers and I'm getting the same error.